# Call simple html page (without AJAX call) using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery, and I'd like to include one html page from another page dynamically using click function.
I have tried using load function but that does not work for me.

Comment: Can't be done! You can't retrieve the contents of an external file on the clientside without somehow contacting the server, and without a reload the only option is ajax.

Comment: Write your code. What have you done with the load function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/.
If you need additional help please tell me.

You can also check the demo http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-sliding-div/#.